# Using alternation or character class for single character matching?

Tags: regex, perl

(Note: Title doesn't seem to clear -- if someone can rephrase this I'm all for it!)

Given this regex: `(.*_e\.txt)`, which matches some filenames, I need to add some other single character suffixes in addition to the `e`. Should I choose a character class or should I use an alternation for this? (Or does it really matter??)

That is, which of the following two seems "better", and why:

a) `(.*(e|f|x)\.txt)`, or

b) `(.*[efx]\.txt)`

Comment: You will be hard pushed to measure __any__ performance difference between the two. Stop worrying and just use the clearest.

Comment: @bobbogo: Note how the question wasn't specifically about performance, but just about "better"+why.

Comment: @Mrtin: I agree completely. Clear code is the priority here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `[efx]` - that's exactly what character classes are designed for: to match one of the included characters. Therefore it's also the most readable and shortest solution.

I don't know if it's faster, but I would be very much surprised if it wasn't. It definitely won't be slower.

My reasoning (without ever having written a regex engine, so this is pure conjecture):

The regex token `[abc]` will be applied in a single step of the regex engine: "Is the next character one of `a`, `b`, or `c`?"

`(a|b|c)` however tells the regex engine to

- remember the current position in the string for backtracking, if necessary
- check if it's possible to match `a`. If so, success. If not:
- check if it's possible to match `b`. If so, success. If not:
- check if it's possible to match `c`. If so, success. If not:
- give up.

Comment: Theoretically the regexp engine could detect that all the alternatives are the same length, so it doesn't need all that backtracking.

Comment: @tim, Exactly !!

Answer (score 15):

Here is a benchmark:

updated according to tchrist comment, the difference is more significant

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @l;
foreach(qw/b c d f g h j k l m n ñ p q r s t v w x z B C D F G H J K L M N ñ P Q R S T V W X Z/) {
    push @l, "abc$_.txt";
}

my $re1 = qr/^(.*(b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|ñ|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|z)\.txt)$/;
my $re2 = qr/^(.*[bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxz]\.txt)$/;
my $cpt;

my $count = -3;
my $r = cmpthese($count, {
    'alternation' => sub {
        for(@l) {
            $cpt++ if $_ =~ $re1;
        }
    },
    'class' => sub {
        for(@l) {
            $cpt++ if $_ =~ $re2;
        }
    }
});
```

**result:**

```
              Rate alternation       class
alternation 2855/s          --        -50%
class       5677/s         99%          --
```

Comment: That’s an interesting — and, I think, useful — illustration. There’s a lot it doesn’t go into though. If you vary the input data, you’ll get different performance, as will you, too, if you vary the patterns.  For example, `[bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxz]` vs `(b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|ñ|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|z)` for Spanish consonants is a lot longer, and presumably should show different performance characteristics.

Comment: I think you should use `use utf8;` pragma because your `$re1` and `$re2` doesn't match same ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With a single character, it's going to have such a minimal difference that it won't matter. (unless you're doing LOTS of operations)

However, for readability (and a slight performance increase) you should be using the character class method.

For a bit further information - opening a round bracket `(` causes Perl to start backtracking for that current position, which, as you don't have further matches to go against, you really don't need for your regex.  A character class will not do this.

Comment: You can have some control over backtracking in a group by using `(?>…)`, the independent subgroup. That way the group itself won’t be revisited once some possibility has been decided on. It’s a bit tricky to use, though.

Comment: @tchrist: far simpler is using just simple `(?:...)` every time you don't want capture subgroup.