# Difference between [abc] and (a|b|c)

Tags: regex, pcre

For PCRE Regular Expressions, what is the difference between [abc] and (a|b|c)?

Comment: Related [Using alternation or character class for single character matching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724588/using-alternation-or-character-class-for-single-character-matching) has some interesting answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The patterns in your question match the same text. In terms of implementation, they correspond to different automata and side effects (*i.e.*, whether they capture substrings).

In a comment below, [Garrett Albright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11023/garrett-albright) points out a subtle distinction. Whereas `(.|\n)` matches any character, `[.\n]` matches either a literal dot or a newline. Although dot is no longer special inside a character class, other characters such as `-`, `^`, and `]` along with sequences such as `[:lower:]` take special meanings inside a character class. Care is necessary to preserve special semantics from one context to the other, but sometimes it isn’t possible such as in the case of `\1` as an archaic way of writing `$1` outside a character class. Inside a character class, `\1` always matches the character SOH.

Character classes (`[...]`) are optimized for matching one out of some set of characters, and alternatives (`x|y`) allow for more general choices of varying lengths. You will tend to see better performance if you keep these design principles in mind. Regex implementations transform source code such as `/[abc]/` into finite-state automata, usually [NFAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). What we think of as regex engines are more-or-less bookkeepers that assist execution of those target state machines. The sufficiently smart regex compiler will generate the same machine code for equivalent regexes, but this is difficult and expensive in the general case because of the [lurking exponential complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Equivalence_to_DFA).

For an accessible introduction to the theory behind regexes, read [“How Regexes Work”](http://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) by Mark Dominus. For deeper study, consider [*An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763714224) by Peter Linz.

Comment: When would you use one over the other?  What do you mean by "they correspond to different automata and substring capturing."?  Thanks

Comment: If a, b and c are just letters only, of course (as I think it's meant). If they could stand for words, it's totally different semantics, obviously.

Comment: I've found that sometimes the square bracket option does not seem to work properly for funny characters such as `\n` or `\r`. For example, to catch all text between FOO and BAR including newline characters, `/FOO((.|\n)+)BAR/` works whereas `/FOO([.\n]+)BAR/` does not. This may be implementation-specific, though. I've found other differences like that I can't recall off the top of my head. At any rate, as a rule, I'll try using `[ab]` first since it's more readable, then give the `(a|b)` a try if things seem to not be working.

Comment: @Garrett Fair point. I assumed all non-special characters. See update.

Comment: (.|\n) and [.\n] are entirely different. The latter only matches to the dot character, and \n. If you want a "dotall", you could also use \p{Any}

Answer (score 1):

(after reading Greg's answer): If they are evaluated differently should be dependent on whatever program you feed them to. Choose on what you are trying to check. Do you want to check against a pool of valid chars, or do you want to check for values. -- That might seem the same sometimes, but it could be a different intention there behind it. Then choose what reflects your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

The form using square brackets is much faster with PCRE, especially if JIT compiling is enabled. It is just checking a bit in a bitset, while the other re-read the character for every alternative. I was thinking about an optimization which would detect such cases, since many do not know that character classes can be used inside square brackets, and they use ([a-z]|\s)+ instead of [a-z\s]+.