# perl, match one of multiple regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I've currently got the following code:

```
if ($str =~ m{^[A-Z]+-\d+$} || $str =~ m{^\d+$}){
    # do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to combine the 2 regular expressions into a single expression?  And would that improve performance at all?

Comment: You may easily combine them using `^(?:[A-Z]+-)?\d+$`

Comment: yes use: `$str =~ m{^(?:[A-Z]+-)?\d+$}`

Comment: What you ask, as answered by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), in the first place improves how the intent is conveyed -- match `\d+` optionally preceded by that other.  It's just clearer that way, than when written with `||`.  Which is faster depends on which case happens more often, but I'd say that _on average_ the single regex should be faster since it never starts the engine twice.

Comment: As a side note, there is an interesting post where [regex optimization in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420517/is-it-faster-to-use-alternation-than-subsequent-replacements-in-regular-expressi/36611087#36611087) is discussed. If the patterns could not be "joined" with an optional non-capuring group, I think it would be more appropriate to just use the `||` with two separate regexps as *"alternations hinder the optimizer"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an optional [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) and combine these two into

```
if ($str =~ m{^(?:[A-Z]+-)?\d+$}) {
    # do stuff
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Z]+-)?` - an optional non-capturing group (`?` quantifier makes it match 1 or 0 times)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: For more complex regexps, consider the `/x` modifier.