# regex with 3 upper case and lower case

Tags: regex

I need regex that checks if string has at least 3 uppercase, 3 lowercase letters and at least one specialcharacter.

Currently I have this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z]{3,})(?=.*[A-Z]{3,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$
```

But it only works if the characters are next to eachother.

Example of what it should match:

```
S4L4S6na#a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*(_|[^\w]))
```

If you want to also include digit

```
(?=.*\d)(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*(_|[^\w]))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA8lS0/1)**

**Further optimization as per comments**

You can use `non-greedy` approach, which optimizes the above `regex` and use `[\W_]` instead of `(_|[^\w])`

```
(?=(.*?[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*?[a-z]){3})(?=.*?[\W_])
```

**[Reason for alternation being slower than character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation)**

Comment: I **think** you'll get better performance if you make `.*` *non-greedy*. I.e. `.*?`. (Probably not an issue, but... ;)

Comment: Yeah, adding the `?` makes it drop from 776 steps to 353 steps. And then appending `.+` makes it drop to 135 steps.

Comment: And for those who love optimization: `(_|[^\w])` > `[\W_]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for telling..didn't knew about it..updated with an explanation of reason