# how to write regular expression to see if at least some statements in expression passed

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions and was wondering how to write a regular expression that would pass if some of the statements in the expression pass.

For example I have this regex

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$
```

which matches if the string has

- 1 lowercase character,
- 1 uppercase character,
- 1 digit,
- 1 symbol.

Is it possible to have a regular expression that would pass if at least 3 of the 4 conditions were true in any order?

(i.e. would pass if string had 1 lower, 1 upper, 1 symbol, or 1 upper, 1 digit, 1 symbol, etc.)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is your programming language?

Comment: Also are the letters and the numbers only english letters and numbers or must you support all languages?

Comment: I am trying to use the RegularExpression attribute in Asp.Net. and yes only english letters. Thanks

Comment: Is it to validate password strength? I have a nice function that can give a score to password in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I can propose you is to capture every type of characters in a capture group and make sure that at least 3/4 capture groups have a value (if the group can't match anything, it should be an empty string).

```
^(?:([a-z])|([A-Z])|(\d)|(_|[^\w]))+$
```

You can also add a positive lookahead to make sure that the password have the required length (by example 8 to 32 characters).

```
^(?=.{8,32}$)(?:([a-z])|([A-Z])|(\d)|(_|[^\w]))+$
```

**Edit**: `([\W_])` is the equivalent of `(_|[^\w])`. Putting the "*W*" in upper case reverse it sense (match all the non-word characters). Moreover, using a single character class is faster than alternation ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141949/4949388))

If you are willing to use javascript, I adapted a function presented in "*[Regular Expression cookbook second edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023630.do)*" for the needs of my website:

```
var PASSWORD_RANKING = {

    TOO_SHORT: 0,
    WEAK: 1,
    MEDIUM: 2,
    STRONG: 3,
    VERY_STRONG: 4
};

/**
* Take a password and returns it's ranking
* based of the strength of the password (length, numeric character, alphabetic character, special character, etc.)
*
* @param password String
* @param minLength Int
*
* @return Int
*/ 
function rankPassword(password, minLength){

    var rank = PASSWORD_RANKING.TOO_SHORT;
    var score = 0;

    if (typeof minLength !== 'number' || minLength < 6){

        minLength = 8;
    }

    if (typeof password === 'string' && password.length >= minLength){

        if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)){ score++;}

        if (/[a-z]/.test(password)){ score++;}

        if (/[0-9]/.test(password)){ score++;}

        if (/[_~!@.#$%^&]/.test(password)){ score++;}

        score += Math.floor((password.length - minLength) / 2);

        if (score < 3){

            rank = PASSWORD_RANKING.WEAK;
        }
        else if (score < 4){

            rank = PASSWORD_RANKING.MEDIUM;
        }
        else if (score < 6){

            rank = PASSWORD_RANKING.STRONG;
        }
        else { 

            rank = PASSWORD_RANKING.VERY_STRONG;
        }
    }

    return rank;
}
```

The section 4.19 present many regexes to enforce password strength. You can see all the code samples online : 
http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920023630/Regex_Cookbook_2_Code_Samples.html

Comment: Thank you for your help Jonathan! much appreciated