# How to remove all instances of 'a' and 'c' in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I remove all instances of two different letters in a string?

For example, I want to remove 'a' and 'c' from 'abcabc' so that it becomes 'bb'.

I know I can't do `'abcabc'.replace(/a/g, '').replace(/c/g, '')` but is there another regEx I can use so that I don't have to chain the `replace` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative syntax:

```
"abcabc".replace(/[ac]/g, '')
```

This creates a custom character group.

Comment: +1 - This is actually [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22132450/2170192), and "scales good" if there are more characters (than two) to be removed. `a|c|e|f|h` vs `[acefh]`

Answer (score 0):

You can separate matches with a pipe:

```
'abcabc'.replace(/a|c/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

`/a|c/g` ought to do it.

`'abcabc'.replace(/a|c/g, '')`