# Regex for recognizing capital letters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am very new to python, I am trying to write a regex that will find all instances of a period, space, then capital letter in a corpora. 
I have this:

```
print (re.findall(r'(\.|\!|\?) (A-Z\w+\b)',text))
```

I got it to print when there was only one capital (i.e. I went to the movie.) but not when its a capitalized word.

Thoughts?

Comment: `re.findall(r'[.!?]\s+[A-Z]',text)`? Note `A-Z` matches a `A-Z` string, `[A-Z]` is a character class that matches uppercase ASCII letters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add some example input and desired output. See [mre] for reference. By the way, please take the [tour].

Comment: Read a regexp tutorial, like www.regular-expressions.info.

Comment: You can also use the regex module (as explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties) with `\p{Lu}` for Unicode uppercase (multiple scripts & languages)

Answer (score 0):

Could use findall using this

`(\.|!|\?) ([A-Z]\w+)`

The word boundary is not needed here.
The alternations can be substituted for a class [.!?] but not necessary.
The `A-Z` is a class item but it needs to be enclosed in square brackets [].

Findall will make two elements per match, the punctuation and the alphanum string.

Comment: You can simplify to `[.!?]`

Comment: `[.!?]` is slower than `\.|!|\?`

Comment: No it's not. It's much faster. 12 steps for [`\.|!|\?`](https://regex101.com/r/anrAx5/1) vs 7 steps for [`[.!?]`](https://regex101.com/r/anrAx5/2) - nearly half the amount of steps.

Comment: `Regex1:   \.|!|\?
 Elapsed Time:    0.15 s,   145.68 ms,   145681 µs
 Matches per sec:   1,029,646
 Regex2:   [.!?]
 Elapsed Time:    0.15 s,   149.08 ms,   149077 µs
 Matches per sec:   1,006,191`

Comment: How are you coming up with those tests, cause they're wrong.

Comment: https://imgur.com/9BSEPN4

Comment: OK now run it 100 more times, it'll fluctuate. See [here](https://tio.run/##lZBBS8NAEIXP2V8x6WV3ISxKb4WSs6AI2puVsCWbOpjdDZPxUKy/Pa6makuLtO8yMDy@x3vdhl9imA4D@i4SA6N3yAWQE6KHOcjyUOZA@b6kELVrINKdS8xaBT0TGSUGyaXZ5ttlKUXWRAIEDEA2rN3oycjxG6WXMw2G2ratoqLXI67Fno@BTyYvny/FdYSB1WSRKgLbVxdgtYH7B/Df@Bm8f0xMAnrLapzBjEfJ307XV1oWIBuKHqrKWwxVBbvpfkxSa3066/bmcXFG2l7l//L@bF@Jw/AJ). I'm telling you character classes are faster.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation) question and series of answers. Character classes don't cause backtracking whereas alternations do.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/f0IcD1A

Comment: Forget about megabench. Write your own script or check out the one I wrote for you. I can tell you with absolute certainty that character classes are faster since they don't backtrack. If you want you can ask the regex god himself (Wiktor Stribizew - he wrote in the comments); he'll go into more details.

Comment: No overhead, not benchmarking language none involved. Class items are OR 'd just like alternatons, but are slower in the way they are handled.