# Regex replace with bracket variable in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am sure that has been asked before, but I cannot find the appropriate question(s).

Being new to [C#'s Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8), I want to mimic what is possible e.g. with `sed` and `awk` where I would write `s/_(20[0-9]{2})[.0-9]{1}/\1/g` in order to find obtain a 4-digit year number after 2000 which is has an underscore as prefix and a number or a dot afterwards. The `\1` refers to the value within brackets.

**Example:** Both files `fx_201902.csv` or  `fx_2019.csv` should give me back `myYear=2019`. I was not successful with:

```cs
string myYear = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(x), @"_20([0-9]{2})[.0-9]{1}", "\1")
```

How do I have to escape? Or is this kind of replacement not possible? If so, how would I do that?

**Edit:** My issue how to do the `/1` in C#, in other words how to extract a regex-variable. Please forgive me my typos in the original post - I am trying the new SO app and I submitted earlier than intended.

Comment: Is that a typo in the replacement string? It has `"\1"` but should be either `@"\1"` or `"\\1"` or `"$1"`

Comment: @AdrianHH: No, it was not a typo, it was me not knowing what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest more robust regex: `_(20(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))[\d.]`

Explanation:

`_` - match `_` literally

`(...)` - first capturing group

`20` - match `20` literally

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]` - alternation: match 0 and digit other than 0 OR match digit other then zero followed by any digits - this allows you to match ANY year after 2000

`[\d.]` - match dot or digit

And below is how you use capturing groups:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"_(20(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))[\d.]");
regex.Match("fx_201902.csv").Groups[1].Value;
// "2019"
regex.Match("fx_20190.csv").Groups[1].Value;
// "2019"
regex.Match("fx_2019.csv").Groups[1].Value;
// "2019"
```

Comment: An alternation `(\d|\.)` is slower than a character class `[.0-9]` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation

Comment: @Nick thanks for remark... such obvious thing to do (character class is even shorter in terms of code). Corrected

Answer (score 1):

You might use a capturing group for the first 4 digits and match what is before and after the 4 digits.

```
.*_(20[0-9]{2})[0-9]*\.\w+$
```

**Explanation**

- `.*_` Match the last underscore
- `(20[0-9]{2})` Match 20 and 2 digits
- `[0-9]*\.` Match 0 or more occurrences of a digit followed by a dot
- `\w+$` Match 1 or or more word chars till the end of the string.

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*_%2820%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29%5b0-9%5d*%5c.%5cw%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=fx_201902.csv%0d%0afx_2019.csv&r=%241&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/YYqDE5)

In the replacement use:

```
$1
```

For example

```
string[] strings = {"fx_2019.csv", "fx_201902.csv"};
foreach (string s in strings)
{
    string myYear = Regex.Replace(s, @".*_(20[0-9]{2})[0-9]*\.\w+$", "$1");
    Console.WriteLine(myYear);
}
```

Output

```
2019
2019
```

Comment: The Regex is not my issue, the issue is how to do that in c#

Comment: @B--rian I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @Nick You are right of course, it is the sin of copy pasting

Comment: @Thefourthbird regrettably I have sinned that way myself too many times... :-)

Answer (score 1):

To extract the year using `Regex.Replace`, you need to capture only the year part of the string into a group and replace the entire string with just the capture group. That means you need to also match the characters before and after the year using (for example)

```
^.*_(20[0-9]{2})[.0-9].*$
```

That can then be replaced with `$1` e.g.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^.*_(20[0-9]{2})[.0-9].*$");
string filename = "fx_201902.csv";
string myYear = r.Replace(filename, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(myYear);
filename = "fx_2019.csv";
myYear = r.Replace(filename, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(myYear);
```

Output:

```
2019
2019
```

If you want to exclude the year 2000 from your match, change the regex to

```
^.*_(20(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))[.0-9].*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example does not contains the month's digits. If you still want to capture, make it optional:

```
Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(x), @"_20([1-9]{2})([.0-9]{2})?", "\1")
```

Note that I only added 3 characters to your query: ***(***, ***)*** and ***?***

If you want the returning value to be as expected: change the replacement to ***$1*** from ***\1*** as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8) (with the correct parenthesis) and capture 2020, 2030, etc (still excluding 2000) with the usage of ***or operator*** and the combination of ***[0-9]{1}*** and ***[1-9]{1}***:

```
Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileName(x), @"_(20(([1-9]{1})([0-9]{1})||([0-9]{1})([1-9]{1})))([.0-9]{2})?", "$1")
```

It worths mentioning that ***$3*** and ***$4*** matches the last and the 2nd last digit; and ***$2*** matches with the last 2 digits (aka the combination of ***[0-9]{1}*** ***[1-9]{1}*** || ***[1-9]{1}*** ***[0-9]{1}***).