# How to match 2 separate numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that should match when there's two numbers in brackets
`/(P|C\(\d+\,{0,1}\s*\d+\))/g`
for example:

C(1, 2) or P(2 3) //expected to match

C(43) or C(43, ) // expect not to match

but it also matches the ones with only 1 number, how can i fix it?

Comment: The alternation (pipe character "|") in your regex matches a single P character OR the rest of the regex. I recommend replacing that part with a character class... [PC]

Comment: I'd probably write this regex as /[PC]\\(\d(?:,|, )\d\\)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
[PC]\(\d+(?:,| +) *\d+\)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yt1ZyI/2)

**Explanation:**

- `[PC]\(` - matches either `P(` or `C(`
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `(?:,| +)` - matches either a `,` or 1+ spaces
- `*\d+` - matches 0+ spaces followed by 1+ digits
- `\)` - matches `)`

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, your regex will match either `P` on its own or `C` followed by numbers in parentheses; you should replace `P|C` with `[PC]` (you could use `(?:P|C)` but `[PC]` is more performant, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation)). Secondly, since your regex makes both the `,` and spaces optional, it can match `43` without an additional number (the `4` matches the first `\d+` and the `3` the second `\d+`). You need to force the string to either include a `,` or at least one space between the numbers. You can do that with this regex:

```
[PC]\(\d+[ ,]\s*\d+\)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gERyUX/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can relax the separator between the numbers by allowing any combination of command and space by using `\d[,\s]+\d`. Test case:

```js
const regex = /[PC]\(\d+[,\s]+\d+\)/g;
[
  'C(1, 2) or P(2 3)',
  'C(43) or C(43, )'
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(regex);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + JSON.stringify(m));
});
```

Output:

```
C(1, 2) or P(2 3) ==> ["C(1, 2)","P(2 3)"]
C(43) or C(43, ) ==> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should require the presence of at least one delimiting character between the numbers.

I suppose you want to get the numbers out of it separately, like in an array of numbers:

```js
let tests = [
    "C(1, 2)",
    "P(2 3)",
    "C(43)",
    "C(43, )"
];

for (let test of tests) {
    console.log(
        test.match(/[PC]\((\d+)[,\s]+(\d+)\)/)?.slice(1)?.map(Number)
    );
}
```