# Regex includes Lookahead strings in selection

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookahead

I'm trying to extract the degree (`Mild`/`Moderate`/`Severe`) of an specific type heart dysfunction (diastolic dysfunction) from a huge number of echo reports.

[Here is the link to the sample excel file with 2 of those echo reports](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Id2swuBaxSbeTDtZYDKsrNOsSXUnsLxy/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116734085108216576136&rtpof=true&sd=true).

The lines are usually expressed like this: "**Mild** LV diastolic dysfunction" or "**Mild** diastolic dysfunction". Here, "**Mild**" is what I want to extract.

I wrote the following pattern:

```
pattern <- regex("(\\b\\w+\\b)(?= (lv )?(d(i|y)astolic|distolic) d(y|i)sfunction)",
                               ignore_case = FALSE)
```

Now, let's look at the results (remember I want the "Mild" part not the "LV" part):

```
str_view_all(df$echo, pattern)
```

As you can see in strings like "Mild diastolic dysfunction" the pattern correctly selects "Mild", but when it comes to "Mild LV diastolic dysfunction" pattern selects "LV" even though I have brought the `lv` inside a positive lookahead `(?= ( lv)?)` construct.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\w+` matches any one or more word chars, and the lookahead does not consume the chars it matches (the regex index remains where it was).

So, the `LV` gets matched with `\w+` as there is `diastolic dysfunction` right after it, and  `( lv)?` is an *optional* group (there may be no space+`lv` right before `diastolic dysfunction`) for the `\w+` to match).

If you do not want to match `LV`, add a negative lookahead to restrict what `\w+` matches:

```r
\b(?!lv\b)\w+\b(?=(?:\s+lv)?\s+d(?:[iy]a|i)stolic d[yi]sfunction)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSJEYW/1)

Also, note that `[iy]` is a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation) to write `(i|y)`.

In R, you may define it as

```r
pattern <- regex(
    "\\b(?!lv\\b)\\w+\\b(?=(?:\\s+lv)?\\s+d(?:[iy]a|i)stolic\\s+d[yi]sfunction)",
    ignore_case = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor for the quick answers, but I'm a bit confused on why in `(?= (lv )?(d[iy]astolic|distolic) d[yi]sfunction)` the lookahead hides the `(d[iy]astolic|distolic) d[yi]sfunction)` part from the str_view() results but not the `( lv)?` part. both of them come after the positive lookahead.

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh `( lv)?` is an *optional* group. So, the `\w+` also matches before both `lv distolic dysfunction` and `distolic dysfunction`.

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor, for being out there looking after rookies like me.

Comment: sorry again, but with the pattern you wrote, str_view() still selects the "LV" parts

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh The regex does not match them.

Comment: [but it still does](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vc4VozUC5KOtDPtVniQ8P8BYCH_vrNlu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh No, [it does **NOT**](https://imgur.com/a/fTxpozk)

Comment: I forgot to set the ignore_case = TRUE. this will fix the problem in str_view() **BUT** the problem persists when I want to use tidyr::extract() function. `extract(df, echo, c("diastolic dysfunction"), pattern)`

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh `extract(df, echo, c("diastolic dysfunction"), "(?i)\\b(?!lv\\b)(\\w+)\\b(?=(?:\\s+lv)?\\s+d(?:[iy]a|i)stolic\\s+d[yi]sfunction)")` works for me.

Comment: I now I understand what is wrong, apparently `regex()` arguments (such as `ignore_case = TRUE`) only work with functions from `stringr` package and not with the `tidyr::extract()` function. so instead of the `regex("pattern", ignore_case = TRUE)` I have to use `"(?i)pattern"` just as you did. thanks again. that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\w+` can also match LV and the `lv`  part is optional.

Instead of a lookahead, you can also use a capture group.

```
\b(?!lv)(\w+)\b (?:lv )?(?:d[iy]astolic|distolic) d[iy]sfunction
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZwF2f/1)

Comment: thanks, I think I will use a combination of lookarounds and non-capturing groups