# Optimize regex to read date

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have developed a regex to use in a .NET WebAPI that gets a date and a control code from a given input already formatted in final format.

I tried regex to avoid using multiple string splits.

I've been using Regex101 to test my expression and I have one that already works as expected by I think it's too large for what it does.

Expression:

```
^([0-9]{2})+([0-9]{2})+([0-9]{2})[0-9](M|F)([0-9]{2})+([0-9]{2})+([0-9]{2})
```

// Get in format Year, Month, Day, Code(M|F), Year, Month, Day

Input:

```
7603259M2209058PRT<<<<<<<<<<<8
```

Do you have any suggestions to simplify it?

Comment: 1) The `+` are wrong in your pattern, remove them all, 2) use `\d` to match a digit, and pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option, 3) do not use alterantion with single chars, use a character class. `new Regex(@"^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d([MF])(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`

Comment: How does `2209058` describe "Year, Month, Day"? Year = 22, Month = 09, Day = 058???

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen year=22, Month=09, Day=05 thats why I'm expecting one more digit before Code(M|F)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the advice, I kept the [0-9] because it's equivalent to \d , I don't really know if the engine transform \d to [0-9] or how it woks. 
I just would like to have less statements.

Comment: In that case @WiktorStribiżew is spot on, you don't need all those open-ended quantifiers. `^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})[0-9][MF]([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})` should do

Comment: `\d` with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` = `[0-9]`, else, `\d` = `\p{Nd}`

Comment: `\d` != `[0-9]` by default - `\d` will match non-latin numeric digits too, eg. `๔` (4 in Thai numerals)

Comment: Wasn't aware thanks for the explanation but in this case I think [0-9] will fit best because I'm not expecting non-latin numerics. This is data provided by a CSV file.

Comment: @JoãoMendes If you read my comments and answer (and see the online demo) you will see that `\d` with `ECMAScript` option does not match any Thai digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue with your regex: you quantified the two-digit matching capturing groups with a `+` quantifier, making them match one or more times. `([0-9]{2})+` matches one or more sequences of any two ASCII digits, while keeping the last captured value in the corresponding group. See [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

You need to remove all `+` chars from your pattern and then you can also use the following:

- Use `\d` to match any digit while passing the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the regex compile method so that it can only match ASCII digits (otherwise, `\d` will be equal to `\p{Nd}` and will match any Unicode digits, see [\d less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/3832970))
- Instead of alterantion with single chars (`(M|F)`), use a character class, `([MF])`, this is more efficient (see [Why is a character class faster than alternation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22132450/3832970)).

You can use

```cs
var pattern = new Regex(@"^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d([MF])(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5Cd%28%5BMF%5D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29&i=760325%E0%B9%94M2209058PRT%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C8%0D%0A7603259M2209058PRT%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C8&o=me).

If you want to use and even shorter regex you may use:

```cs
var pattern = new Regex(@"^(?:(\d{2})){3}\d([MF])(?:(\d{2})){3}", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
var match = pattern.Match("7603259M2209058PRT<<<<<<<<<<<8");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value); // => 76
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Captures[1].Value); // => 03
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Captures[2].Value); // => 25
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);             // => M
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Captures[0].Value); // => 22
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Captures[1].Value); // => 09
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Captures[2].Value); // => 05
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/PdHCHQ) and [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%28%5BMF%5D%29%28%3F%3A%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29%7B3%7D&i=760325%E0%B9%94M2209058PRT%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C8%0D%0A7603259M2209058PRT%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C8&o=me).

Note this is possible because .NET `Regex` allows access to all the captures inside the group stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I applied your suggestion. 
I would like to find a way to make Regex expression smaller instead of repeating the pattern to create the group "(\d{2})" 6 times

Comment: @JoãoMendes I added another solution with repeated capturing groups, but note it is not quite portable, and less intuitive. Shorter in regex world does not always mean better.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I had something like this but in Regex101 it was not showing as a captured value so I thought it wouldn't work. 
I will keep the advice to be careful that it doesn't work everywhere but in my case I think it's the best fit.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoãoMendes Make sure you test your patterns at a *compatible* online regex tester. Regex101 does not support .NET regex flavor.