# Splitting text at certain characters OR after a certain number of characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some basic regex to split text based on some simple characters

```
/(\.|"|0-9|!|\?|,|:|;|¡|¿|჻|·|…|؟|،|॥|।|«|\(|\)|\{|»|<|>|⸗|⸚|֊|᛫|᠂|᠃|᠅|⁏|።|፣|、|。|‥|「|」|『|』|〝|〟|“|”|，|—)/
```

But I would like to also split the text if a certain block of text goes on long enough without any of these characters. Is this possible with regex?

Comment: `.{x}`  as your last alternation. Where `x` is the number of characters

Comment: You can use split("") for splitting every char of a string.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I just add that to the end of the regex?

Edit: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: You should use a character class, not an alternation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation

Comment: @Nick Thank you! I wasn't aware that it was slower.

Comment: @DingleberrySmith no worries. It also has the advantage that you don't need to escape characters inside a class. The one thing you need to be careful of is putting a `-` (if there is one) at either the beginning or end of the class, otherwise it is interpreted as part of a range (as in for example `0-9`).

Comment: @DingleberrySmith yah as @nick alluded to, the regex could be cleaned up a lot in general. A note that the part I mentioned should NOT be in the char class; it should remain as an alternation. So e.g. `/[."0-9!?]|.{x}/`

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thank you for the suggestion. Quick question though. How can I do this with combinations of characters like (gh) or a period followed by a space? I tried just wrapping them in parentheses but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DingleberrySmith character classes only match a single character at a time. If you want to match a pattern involving more, you have to do it as an alternation, e.g. `/[."0-9!?]|\.\s|.{x}/`