# Java Regex to replace double quotes with single quotes for HTML attributes, getting issue with Sonar Analysis

Tags: java, regex

I have a below string in Java

`String text = "<link href=\"https://example.com\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /> <link href=\"https://example.com\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /> <div class=\"fr-view\"> <div></div><p>analyst</p> </div>";`

Expected Output:

`text = <link href='https://example.com' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> <link href='https://example.com' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> <div class='fr-view'> <div></div><p>analyst</p> </div>`

Basically I want to replace the html attributed in double quotes with single quotes. I have used below regex which works perfectly but I get the sonar issue.

`text.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}|\"|\\\\", "'");`

Sonar issue I am facing with above regex is "Single-character alternations in regular expressions should be replaced with character classes".

Can anyone suggest the alternate regex to achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: I think it means you should express the alternatives as `"[\\p{Cntrl}\"\\\\]"` but I'm not sure.  I haven't seen this particular Sonar message before.

Comment: Why do you look for \ and control characters in your regex at all? To replace a quote character you just have to look for exactly that one, you wouldn't even have to use a regular expression for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `"\\p{Cntrl}|\"|\\\\"` string literal. It represents the following regex - `\p{Cntrl}|"|\\` that matches any control character, or a double quotation mark, or a backslash.

In order to resolve the "Single-character alternations in regular expressions should be replaced with character classes" issue, you need to place these three elements into a character class, i.e. in between `[...]`:

```java
text.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}\"\\\\]", "'");
```

Now, it represents a `[\p{Cntrl}"\\]` pattern that matches the same three chars as before, but [more efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22132450/3832970).