# How to write a generical REGEX expression to: Σ = {a, b, c}, L = {w ∈ Σ ∗ / the first symbol of w is equal to the last symbol of w}?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I tried `^(a|b|c)?(a|b|c)*\1$` and some variations but for some reason words like `a` or `b` aren't captured. Could you guys explain me why?

I also don't get why in the expression `^(a|b|c)?(a|b|c)\1$` the word `cac` is captured. I mean, I thought in this expression the word should just have 2 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No string less than length 2 can match `^(a|b|c)?(a|b|c)*\1$`

- `(a|b|c)*` matches 0 or more characters
- `\1` is required and matches exactly 1 character
- if `\1` matches, there must be an additional `(a|b|c)` at the start of the line

---

`^(a|b|c)?(a|b|c)\1$` can only be matched by strings of **exactly** length 3:

- The second `(a|b|c)` matches exactly 1 character
- `\1` is required and matches exactly 1 character
- if `\1` matches, there must be an additional `(a|b|c)` at the start of the line

Comment: One would typically code `(a|b|c)` as `[abc]`

Answer (score 1):

Words like `a` or `b` are not captured because they don't have a repeating sequence of characters at the end and the expression requires the backreference `\1` to match a character that was captured by the first group,since the first group is optional, if it doesn't capture anything, the backreference won't find a match, and in the expression `^(a|b|c)?(a|b|c)\1$`, the word `cac` is captured because the first group `(^(a|b|c)?)` is optional and it can match either `a`, `b`, or `c`. In your case, it matches `c` and also the second group `(a|b|c)` matches `a` and the backreference `\1` then matches the same `c` captured by the first group,so the word `cac` satisfies the condition of having a repeating sequence of characters at the end!

Answer (score 0):

@jhnc has explained the issues with your regex. If you *want* to match single character strings, you will need to modify your regex to make the rest of the match optional:

```
^([abc])(?:[abc]*\1)?$
```

This will match:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `([abc])` : one of `a`, `b`, or `c`, captured in group 1
- `(?:[abc]*\1)?` : an optional group consisting of 0 or more `a`, `b` or `c` followed by the character matched in group 1
- `$` : end of string

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/J68vYl/1)

Note that if you only want to match single characters [a character class is more efficient than an alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132450/why-is-a-character-class-faster-than-alternation).