# How to create a regex that match "/ but not "/" or "/a (only "/)?

Tags: regex

I need a regex which can match `"/` but not `"/"` or `"/>`. So for example:

- `"/hello"` : match the `"/`
- `"/cool.php"` : match the `"/`
- `a + "/" + b` : do not match
- `<input name="hello"/>` : do not match

Using regex builder, I've managed to create a regex `"\/[^\>"]` which match `"/` but plus one character. So `"/hello"` will match `"/h`. This is wrong.

I'm a little newbie on regex. What's wrong in my regex? Can you fix it and probably give a little explanation of why it's wrong and what part do you fix and why?

Comment: Which programming language will this Regex run on? (BTW it looks like you're trying to parse HTML with Regex...)

Comment: @PranavCBalan hey that works wonderfully! You should make your comment an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use look [positive ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
"\/(?=[^>"]|$)
```

---

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/dC1zN2/4)**

Comment: That doesn't match the string `"/` alone

Comment: @Bergi : that depends on user need, anyway it can done `"\/(?=[^\>"]|$)`

Comment: Indeed it does, but one needs to be aware of the difference.

Comment: @PranavCBalan your original regex is working fine and I have tested, it can also recognise `"/` alone. What is the `|$` do?

Comment: @Bergi 's *negative* look ahead is more elegant and readable.

Comment: @ChenLiYong : to match if it's at the end of the string.... I think negative look ahead is better readable

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"\/(?!"|>)
```

Comment: I guess `"\/(?![">])` is a bit more streamlined.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: But one character longer! OMG :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no: `"|>` is shorter than `[">]`

Comment: Shorter does not mean more efficient when it comes to  regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew efficient does not mean better. When the difference in performance is minuscule (as here), readability wins (for me).

Comment: This is great and gives me some perspective to build a regex with the same behaviour using different approach. :)

Comment: @Bergi No need to escape the slash

Comment: @Bohemian: Depends on the language where it is used, the slash is a popular literal delimiter (and the OP escaped it as well)

Comment: @Bergi Escaping a backslash is technically not part of the regex, and the language would signal a syntax error in the case that it was needed, making it obvious. Many devs unnecessarily escape the backslash in non-backslash delimiting languages..

Comment: @Bohemian: It depends what you count. I see 1 *branch* inside the lookahead. With the alternation, there are 2 branches. 1 is less than 2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: What is a character class if not syntactical sugar for branching?

Comment: Bergi, a character class is compiled as one atom, it is not an alternation group alternative.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, a character class is an atom, but does that mean a regex engine does compile and optimise it any differently?

Comment: Yes. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141949/3832970) you can check how backtracking works with alternation and character class. Also, Toto's and Tim Pietzcker's answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724588/using-alternation-or-character-class-for-single-character-matching) are worthy of checking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: However Unihedron mentions that the prce engine does optimise this case :-)

Comment: Optimizes character classes, yes, but not alternation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I believe he meant that the engine optimises an alternation of single literal characters *away* into a character class. That's why he needed to disable optimisations for the screenshot.