# Split from text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text likes

> input = ID-name-birth

I want to extract the ID, name and birth separately. So I used

```
ID= input.split('-')[0]
name= input.split('-')[1]
birth = input.split('-')[2]
```

It worked. But sometimes, my customer insert likes

> input = ID_name_birth

So I need to change the code to

```
ID= input.split('_')[0]
name= input.split('_')[1]
birth = input.split('_')[2]
```

I want to make my code work any situation wherever insert '_' nor '-'. Do we have an option to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), and you also do not need to call it 3 times, use unpacking:

```
import re

for input_str in 'id-name-birth', 'id_name_birth':
    ID, name, birth = re.split('[-_]', input_str)
    print(ID, name, birth)
```

Outputs

```
id name birth
id name birth
```

Comment: I would prefer using or like `'-|_'` than square brackets.

Comment: Thanks. How about `input = ID_name_birth.txt`, and I only want to get `ID,name,birth`. And also, sometimes the input is ID_name_birth_city. In your code, we need to feed four input to receive likes `ID, name, birth, city = re.split('[-_]', input_str)`, but accutually, I only care about ID, name, and birth. Can we get it without knowledge how many input should be pass

Comment: @Austin It's actually an anti-pattern to use `|` with single-characters, and character class is faster in this case ("single character alteration") -  See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724588/using-alternation-or-character-class-for-single-character-matching

Comment: @John, you can discard the rest with "extended unpacking": `ID, name, birth, *_ = re.split('[-_]', input_str)`