# Comparing two regex expressions for efficiency

Tags: regex

Why is:

```
[\s\S]+?
```

Much more efficient than:

```
(?:.|\n)+?
```

What are the differences between the two in terms of how they work behind the scenes?

Note: this is with `DOTALL` turned off. Also, from https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html:

> JavaScript and VBScript do not have an option to make the dot match line break characters. In those languages, you can use a character class such as `[\s\S]` to match any character. This character matches a character that is either a whitespace character (including line break characters), or a character that is not a whitespace character. Since all characters are either whitespace or non-whitespace, this character class matches any character.

Comment: First version is single step, whereas second version is 3 steps, according to regex101

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724588/using-alternation-or-character-class-for-single-character-matching?rq=1

Comment: Those are not equivalent expressions. I think you need `(?:.|\r?\n)+?`

Comment: Never use alternation when you can use a character set instead. Alternation causes the engine to split into matching two subpatterns, which causes extra overhead due to backtracking. A character set simply looks for one of the characters and moves on. Also note that `[\s\S]+?` is not functionally synonymous with `(?:.|\n)+?` A set containing a class and its negation such as `[\s\S]` will match *anything* that isn't zero-length. `.|\n` is more specific, and excludes non-\n newline characters such as `\r`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4724588/2191572 is also relevant

Comment: [Here is a benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4724840/372239)