# How to match 'a' or '^'

Tags: regex

To this question I had answered a|\^ but was told that the expected answer is [a^]
Is the latter solution more efficient than former?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk the question is fine, clear and to the point.

Comment: Have you done a benchmark?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4724840/372239

Answer (score 6):

Both solutions are valid and fundamentally achieve the same goal. `[a^]` *may* be more efficient depending on the regex implementation in question — when parsing the regex, the engine knows that anything within `[]` must match a single character, whereas `|` can handle arbitrary-length alternatives — however, this is **purely speculation** and I would venture to guess that most real regex engines handle this common case quite efficiently. Unless you plan to [benchmark your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304271/23649) to determine which parts are bottlenecks, they can be considered equivalent.

There are some other minor tradeoffs; for instance, `[a^]` doesn't require wrapping in `()` if you are putting it next to something, but `a|\^` does. IMO, `[a^]` is confusing because it looks like someone tried to write `[^a]` (any character except `a`) but made a typo. However, `(?:a|\^)` is quite verbose. Weighing these tradeoffs is a stylistic/subjective matter.

Comment: thank you, could you please explain how [a^] is more efficient than a|\^

Answer (score 1):

```
Comparison:
            a|\^:    23518.6 i/s
            [a^]:    22498.6 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
```

With regard to your question on efficiency, there isn't a big performance difference with the test I ran, although you could do some more intensive performance testing. The results of the test above are based on this [article](https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698) which uses ruby and the [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) gem.

Comment: What language/library did you run this test with? It’s meaningless otherwise :)

Comment: As mentioned above, I based my performance testing on the linked article which uses ruby and the benchmark-ips gem.  I'll update the post to say so explicitly so you don't have to click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` operator matches either of the two expressions. For example, `hello|w.[4]` would match:

```
hello
world
warst
```

Whereas, `[ba\^]` matches any of the characters between `[` and `]`. For example `[ba\^]` would match:

```
b
a
^
```

For the case that you presented, they're essentially the same. As for performance, I benchmarked both using JavaScript and the results were inconsistent. Although, I don't think one has a major performance difference over the other. You can checkout how I benchmarked it [here](http://jsben.ch/K7juG).