# Regex [] vs () in Python with respect to re.split()

Tags: python, regex, split, capturing-group, character-class

What is the difference between [,.] and (,|.) when used as a pattern in re.split(pattern,string)? Can some please explain with respect to this example in Python:

```
import re
regex_pattern1 = r"[,\.]"
regex_pattern2 = r"(,|\.)"
print(re.split(regex_pattern1, '100,000.00')) #['100', '000', '00']
print(re.split(regex_pattern2, '100,000.00'))) #['100', ',', '000', '.', '00']
```

Comment: The first one is a _character class_ and the second is a _capture group_

Comment: You may also want to check: [Using alternation or character class for single character matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4724588/8967612)

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a page that did not explain `split`'s behaviour at all.

Comment: Sorry I guess my title wasn't clear, what I wanted to ask was why character class and capture group works diffrently with respect to re.split()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`[,\.]` is equivalent to `,|\.`.<sup>[1]</sup>

`(,|\.)` is equivalent to `([,\.])`.

`()` creates a capture, and `re.split` returns captured text as well as the text separated by the pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'([,\.])', '100,000.00')
['100', ',', '000', '.', '00']
>>> re.split(r'(,|\.)', '100,000.00')
['100', ',', '000', '.', '00']
>>> re.split(r',|\.', '100,000.00')
['100', '000', '00']
>>> re.split(r'(?:,|\.)', '100,000.00')
['100', '000', '00']
>>> re.split(r'[,\.]', '100,000.00')
['100', '000', '00']
```

---

1. You might sometime need `(?:,|\.)` to limit what is considered the operands of `|` when you embed it in a larger pattern, though.

Comment: The `.` does not need to be escaped in a character class, so it can be `[,.]`